# Process builder skipping a filter?

Tags: process-builder, system-admin

I have create a process builder that I want to be trigger only if the stage is changed and it has a particular value in the picklist, and a field in my opportunity ln__c is not empty and was changed too

The problem i am having is that the process is being triggered, each time the stage is change regardless of ln__c been changed, it is like if it is not respecting the rules regarding ln__c. So if the stage was accidentally moved and there was a value in ln__c when the opportunity stage is move back to loan funded, i end up with 2 records created

This is how i have the process builder set up, or will be just safer to do this in a trigger?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the criteria node, expand the "Advanced" section and check the box that reads "Yes" under "Do you want to execute the actions only when specified changes are made to the record?" This will cause the criteria to execute only once when the criteria is met.